# Google Street View Custom Panorama Exits On Missed Click

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm using Google Street View's [custom panorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomStreetView) feature on a website I'm building. I noticed that if you try to move inside the custom panoramas with custom links defined, and you accidentally miss the link arrow, Street View exits the custom panorama back to street view panorama adjacent (but not exactly) the one you had defined as entry point.

I noticed that it happens in the [example in Google's API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-tiles) as well.

Anyone know if there's any workaround for this?

Update: Here's an image, where I've circled roughly the area where clicking causes this https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzA9C.jpg

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen in Firefox (or I don't understand how to replicate the problem), what browsers does this happen in?

Comment: I tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE 10 and it happens in all of them. Unfortunately I can't link to my test site, but you can replicate it on the Google's example I linked by clicking close to, but not exactly, the arrow once you've entered the custom panorama of Google's Sydney office.